# How do I make the dialogue visibility a toggle based on user input?

Tags: unity, c#

So the code is working but when I press <kbd>F</kbd> key again it starts from the beginning but I want it to disappear and if the player wants to see it again to press the <kbd>F</kbd> key once more to see the dialogue again. I know that my mistake is in the void `EndDialogue()` but I don't know how to fix it.

This is the dialogue script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject window;
    public GameObject indicator;
    public TMP_Text dialogueText;
    public List<string> dialogues;
    public float writingSpeed;
    public int index;
    private int charIndex;
    public bool started;
    private bool waitForNext;
    private void Awake()
    {
        ToggleIndicator(false);
        ToggleWindow(false);
        started = false;
    }
    public void ToggleWindow(bool show)
    {
        window.SetActive(show);
    }
    public void ToggleIndicator(bool show)
    {
        indicator.SetActive(show);
    }
    public void StartDialogue()
    {
        if (started)
            return;
        if (waitForNext)
            return;
        started = true;
        ToggleWindow(true);
        ToggleIndicator(true);
        GetDialogue(0);
    }
    private void GetDialogue(int i)
    {
        index = i;
        charIndex = 0;
        dialogueText.text = string.Empty;
        StartCoroutine(Writing());
    }
    public void EndDialogue()
    {
        started = false;
        waitForNext = false;
        StopAllCoroutines();
        ToggleWindow(false);
    }
    IEnumerator Writing()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(writingSpeed);
        string currentDialogue = dialogues[index];
        dialogueText.text += currentDialogue[charIndex];
        charIndex++;
        if (charIndex < currentDialogue.Length)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(writingSpeed);
            StartCoroutine(Writing());
        }
        else
        {
            waitForNext = true;
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
            if (!started)
                return;
        if (waitForNext && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
            {
                waitForNext = false;
                index++;
            if (index < dialogues.Count)
            {
                GetDialogue(index);
            }
            else
            {
                ToggleIndicator(true);
                EndDialogue();
            }
        }
 
    }
}
```

and this is the dialogue trigger script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dialogue dialogueScript;
    private bool playerDetected;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerDetected = true;
            dialogueScript.ToggleIndicator(playerDetected);
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerDetected = false;
            dialogueScript.ToggleIndicator(playerDetected);
            dialogueScript.EndDialogue();
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (playerDetected && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F ))
        {
            dialogueScript.StartDialogue();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it: I just had to move the void `Update()` from the dialogue script to the dialogue trigger script and it worked perfectly.